# PL/SQL запрос

Tags: oracle, plsql

Добрый день! Вопрос такой. Имеется две таблицы: одна родительская и одна дочерняя - Asubtypeo и aevent соответственно. В таблице Asubtypeo хранятся справочные данные, где первичный ключ ID_Subtype. В таблице aevent связанное поле Code_subtype не везде заполнено кодами из ID_Subtype. Вопрос: как включить в выборку все значения, пустые и заполненные Code_subtype, а не только заполненные, при связке с таблицей Asubtypeo? Слышал, что NVL может помочь в этом вопросе...

Как дописать ниже следующий код:

```
Select a.*, b.* from sevent a, Asubtypeo b WHERE (ID_Subtype = Code_subtype)
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понял Вас, что в дочерней таблице хранятся "ничьи дети"? Так не должно и не может быть. Необходимо менять концепцию вместе со схемой.

Comment: Можно попробовать связать таблицы через односторонний join (left join или right join).

Answer (score 2):

Вам не нужен nvl, вам нужен outer join.

В оракле, если я правильно помню, это делается так:

```
Select a.*, b.* 
  from sevent a, 
       Asubtypeo b 
 WHERE b.ID_Subtype (+) = a.Code_subtype
```

Если я неправильно вспомнил синтаксис, то можно более классическим способом:

```
Select a.*, b.* 
  from sevent a 
       left join Asubtypeo b 
              on ID_Subtype = Code_subtype
```

Подробный мануал можно найти здесь:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm

Comment: Спасибо, попробую).